# A pendulum clock is put at a height

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

[image]

[image]

This is a physics bowl question. I cannot understand the two red circles. The question says '...clock has a period of 1.0s', but why the solution says T0 is 2.
In addition, what's the meaning of '43,200 cycles'?

Comment: I find this $2$ to be entirely superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

All they are doing is simplifying the maths for themselves. If you keep to the definition of period (i.e 1 full cycle is one period), then it should read

$$2T=2T_0(1+\frac{h}{R})$$
Where all they did was multiply by 2 both sides before plugging in $T_0$. There is nothing wrong with this.

Next, to find $$\Delta T=n(T-T_0)$$ where $n$ is the number of cycles it takes the original clock to complete a day, $86400$, instead they are actually doing
$$\Delta T = \frac{n}{2}(2T-2T_0)$$
So thats where the $43200$ comes from. They are looking at $2T-2T_0 =0.0001$ because it will be easier to do the arithmetic.

So in short, they are written confusingly.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong just they have provided very implicit solution.

Actually they assumed To = 2 sec (let's say it's one cycle so a day has 86,400 sec ie 43,200 cycles) and found corresponding T (which came out to be 2.0001) then subtracted them to find time lag for a single cycle, multiply it by total cycles in a day to find how much the clock at height will lose per day.

You may very well take To = 1sec and find corresponding lag then multiply it by no of per day, you will end with same answer!